# iOS 10 Simulator LayerKit connection failed

Tags: ios-simulator, ios10, macos-sierra, layerkit

After moving to latest mac OS Sierra and Xcode 8, LayerKit(version 0.22.0) stop working on simulator. Always return error:

Error Domain=com.layer.LayerKit.Security Code=-34018 "Generation of key pair failed with result code -34018." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Generation of key pair failed with result code -34018., parameters={
    atag = <63657274 732d7472 75737465 642e6c79 72382e6e 65743a43 46363431 3046342d 42383546 2d313145 342d4134 42452d34 37424235 46303235 444534>;
    bsiz = 1024;
    pdmn = ck;
    perm = 1;
    type = 42;
}}

Does anyone have the same problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Enable "Keychain Sharing" fix this issue. Look this thread https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/60617

[image]